# Sorting and Grouping Domains and Subdomains

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, utilities

Is there a better way of sorting and grouping domains and subdomains together? For e.g., the file `list` containing

```
morefu.sub1.foo.com
www.foo.com
bar.foo.com
sub1.foo.com 
fufu.isub1.foo.com
foofoo.bar.foo.com 
morefoo.bar.foo.com
fufu.sub1.foo.com
```

using

```
for i in $(grep -oP '(\w+).foo.com' list | sort | uniq); do grep $i list | sort; echo; done
```

almost works:

```
bar.foo.com
foofoo.bar.foo.com 
lotsmorefubar.bar.foo.com
morefoo.bar.foo.com

fufu.isub1.foo.com <-- should not be here
fufu.sub1.foo.com
morefu.sub1.foo.com
sub1.foo.com 

www.foo.com
```

with the exception of `fufu.isub1.foo.com` which should be in a section by itself. Adding `^` and `\b` to the grep expression did not help.

Wondering if there is a more accurate and efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
tr -d [:blank:] < hosts |                           # remove trailing whitespace
perl -lne 'print join ".", reverse(split /\./)' |   # reverse order of fields
sort |                                              # sort
awk -F. '
  !seen[$1.$2.$3]++ && NR>1 {print ""}             # insert blank line when tld,dom,sub change
  {for (i=NF;i>1;i--) printf "%s.", $i; print $1}   # print fields in original order
'
```

giving

```
bar.foo.com
foofoo.bar.foo.com
morefoo.bar.foo.com

fufu.isub1.foo.com

sub1.foo.com
fufu.sub1.foo.com
morefu.sub1.foo.com

www.foo.com
```

---

Better (I hope) implementation of the same algorithm, using a [hash of hashes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch09_04.htm) in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %domains = ();

while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
  chomp $_ ;
  $_ =~ s/\s+//;

  my @F = reverse(split(/\./));
  my $domain = join(".", @F[0..2]);

  if ( ! exists($domains{$domain}) ) {
    $domains{$domain} = {};
  }

  $domains{$domain}{join(".", @F)}++;
}

foreach my $domain (sort keys %domains) {
  foreach my $host (sort keys %{ $domains{$domain} }) {
    print join(".", reverse(split(/\./, $host))), "\n";
  }
  print "\n"
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Pardon me, I know I didn't ask for it in my question, but would there be a way to sort within a group? For e.g., the 2nd last set would be: `bar.foo.com foofoo.bar.foo.com morefoo.bar.foo.com`. Not looking for answer per sé, but a hint in the right direction; I tried `... | awk ... | sort | rev` which works, but the blank lines disappear.

Comment: @KM. please see updated answer which reverses the order of the *fields* (instead of using `rev` to reverse the whole string). Note: if I was smarter, I'd probably be able to do it all in perl (using a hash in place of the awk array).

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](http://nongnu.org) Lisp:

```
[(opip (mapcar (op tok-str @1 #/[^.]+/))
       (sort @1 : reverse)
       (partition-by (ret [@1 -3..-1]))
       (mapcar (op mapcar (op cat-str @1 ".")))
       (interpose "")
       tprint)
 (get-lines)]
```

Run:

```
$ txr domain-sort.tl < data
bar.foo.com
foofoo.bar.foo.com
morefoo.bar.foo.com

fufu.isub1.foo.com

sub1.foo.com
fufu.sub1.foo.com
morefu.sub1.foo.com

www.foo.com
```

Basically we tokenize the lines into lists of strings like `("sub1" "foo" "com")`, and work with a list of these. We sort this list using the reverse of its elements as the key; so for the purposes of sorting, `("sub1" "foo" "com")` is treated as if it were `("com" "sub1" "foo")`.  After that, it's a matter of grouping. That is easily achieved using `partition-by`, using the last three elements as the partitioning key. We have to reconstitute the strings by joining them with a period, and print the groups with lines. The latter is achieved by inserting empty string among the groups, and letting `tprint` do its job.